# TypeError while writing scraped links to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

As I was working on a small web-scraping bot I ran into this error while trying to write links to a file
`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`
I havent tried much to fix it except for testing the same format with `link + " "` to see if the /n was screwing it up

here's the relevant code I have:

```
input1 = input("enter your dork or search term : ")
print("")

link = "https://search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + input1
print("link to be scraped : " + link)
print("")
print("beginning search... ")
print("")
time.sleep(5)
source = requests.get(link)
bs4call = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source.text, "lxml")
links = bs4call.findAll('a', {'class':'ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24'})

print("links scraped")
time.sleep(.5)
print("")
print("saving links to file : baselinks")
time.sleep(1)

for link in links:
  with open('baselinks.txt', 'a') as out:
    out.write((link) + "/n")
```

---

resolved, and I found out something useful just to document: my goal was to have each individual link printed on its own line... so after printing it as a string with `out.write(str(link) + "\n"` i changed it to `out.write(str(link['href]) + "\n")` that simplified the output to just links.

Thanks for the support

Comment: If you're trying to write a new line on that final line, the character is `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: Also there is no need to open file inside the loop. You should make for loop inside the `with open("baselinks.txt", "a') as out:` context to avoid opening the file multiple times when it's not needed